# jQuery - Load image by selecting option

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, select

I'm trying to display a different image (with a DIV `<div id="Couleur13"></div>`) for each option selected with jQuery, it works when I select another option (but not for the preselected one) and it disappears one second after load.

Here is the HTML (I can't modify this part) :

```
<select class="PB" name="PDTOPTVALUEID0" size="1" OnChange="OnChangeOption();">
    <option value="504031" selected="selected" >NATUREL - BRUT</option>
    <option value="504032">CIRE - TEINTE MOYEN</option>
    <option value="504033">CIRE - TEINTE FONCE</option>
    <option value="504034">COULEUR - NOIR</option>
    <option value="504035">COULEUR - BLANC</option>
    <option value="504036">COULEUR - GRIS SOURIS CLAIR</option>
    <option value="504037">COULEUR - GRIS SOURIS FONCE</option>
    <option value="504038">COULEUR - GRIS PASTEL</option>
    <option value="504041">COULEUR - GRIS ANTHRACITE</option>
    <option value="504043">COULEUR - IVOIRE</option>
    <option value="504044">COULEUR - BEIGE</option>
    <option value="504045">COULEUR - CREME</option>
    <option value="504046">COULEUR - TAUPE</option>
    <option value="504047">COULEUR - JAUNE DOUX</option>
    <option value="504048">COULEUR - ROUGE CARMIN</option>
    <option value="504049">COULEUR - BORDEAUX</option>
    <option value="504050">COULEUR - CHOCOLAT</option>
    <option value="504051">COULEUR - WENGE CLAIR</option>
    <option value="504052">COULEUR - WENGE</option>
    <option value="504053">COULEUR - BLEU AZUR</option>
</select>
```

And here is the jQuery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name=PDTOPTVALUEID0]').change(function() {
        $("#Couleur13").html($("<img />", { src: "http://www.unmeubleenpin.com/" + $(this).val() + ".jpg" }));
    });
});
</script>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('select[name=PDTOPTVALUEID0]').on("change",function() {
         $("#Couleur13").html("<img src='"+$(this).val() + ".jpg'/>");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="Couleur13">
    <img src="default.png"/>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name=PDTOPTVALUEID0]').change(function() {
        var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        $("#Couleur13 > img").attr('src', val + ".jpg");
    });
});
```

But I would suggest you to change src of image, not whole image

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. But maybe it is my fault, I have edited my question because I forgot to add the beginning of the URL and I don't know how (where) add this part in your suggest.

Comment: @laurent34 edited answer. It is not tested but I think it should work

Comment: the images will be stored on another server (http://www.unmeubleenpin.com/), could you edit your answer then I could test it correctly ? Thanks.

Comment: @laurent34 I'll write fiddle in few minutes

Comment: @laurent34 here, it works (some images are not present, see first 2) http://jsfiddle.net/yCKSJ/2/

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work on the website... I don't know why. I have to go but I will be back in 1 hour.

Comment: The problem is that it changes the image but just for one second and after it display automatically the `<img src="http://www.unmeubleenpin.com/504031.jpg"/>`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I looked with developer tools and image src changes properly

Comment: If you have 2 minutes, you can see the result on this page for example : http://www.uninterieur.com/PBSCProduct.asp?ItmID=9368073

Comment: @laurent34 why is the page reloading?

Comment: @laurent34 javascript will be reset if page is reloaded

Comment: What do you mean ? When you change the option ? Because every option has his own images, details, price etc.

Comment: Is there a way to fix that ? I think it is the fault of the OnChange : `function OnChangeOption() {
 var nOptIdx, objSelect, strValues = "", strSep = "", nCurIdx ;
 for ( nOptIdx = 0 ; nOptIdx < 3 ; nOptIdx++ ) {
  objSelect = document.MForm["PDTOPTVALUEID"+nOptIdx] ;
  if ( objSelect ) {
   nCurIdx = objSelect.selectedIndex ;
   if ( nCurIdx >= 0 ) {
    strValue = objSelect.options[nCurIdx].text ;
    strValues = strValues + strSep + strValue ;
    strSep = "]|["
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: you should do it on server side, not with JavaScript. because when you select option, JavaScript changes image source, but page is reloaded and everything resets

Comment: Ha ok, but I can't do it. I have no access to this server... :( Thank you anyway for the help you have given.

Comment: @laurent34 it's bad I could not help :(

Comment: I thought there was a way to fix this that the image displayed depends on whether the option is "selected" or not. But maybe not... Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

`delegate` it

```
$('body').delegate("select[name=PDTOPTVALUEID0]","change",function() {
         $("#Couleur13").html($("<img src='"+$(this).val() + ".jpg'/>");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

trigger `change` on `doc ready` change like this:

```
$('select[name=PDTOPTVALUEID0]').removeAttr('OnChange');
$('select[name=PDTOPTVALUEID0]').change(function() {
   $("#Couleur13").html($("<img />", { src: $(this).val() + ".jpg" }));
}).change(); // <------------trigger it this way here
```

Comment: try removing the inline `OnChange`.

Comment: I can't, I need this Onchange to manage the use of the shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

why you need two onchange functions ? , I guess it creates problem in you case .try execute one

```
1- OnChange="OnChangeOption(); 
2- $('select[name=PDTOPTVALUEID0]').change();
```

Comment: then do onchange logic only in OnChangeOption() function and remove jquery onchange